# Can I use a SOCKS proxy (or any easy to implement proxy) only for specific domains?

Tags: networking, proxy, socks

I have a remote computer that I SSH into, forward a port and use a SOCKS proxy to resolve domains using the remote's network.

On MacOS I have the ability to remove certain domains from being proxied, but not the ability to allow all domains except specified domains.

Is there a way to configure that?

[image]

I have tried using "`**, !important.work.com`" but that didn't work